# Emulator is running, but doesn't execute my program

Tags: android-studio

I'm new in using android studio. I don't have any error, whenever I run my program and the emulator runs, it doesn't execute my program and stays like this.

[image]

Comment: any details about 'Your Porgram' ?

Comment: @aown I am creating a mobile app which has 3buttons and 2 imageButtons. 3buttons are for the PLOT, CASTS, and ABOUT of the TV show. While the 2 imageButtons are icons of fb and youtube. If the user clicks the fb icon, the app will go to the fb page of the show. While if the user clicks the icon of youtube, app will go to the youtube channel of the show

Answer (score 0):

it happens sometimes, 
probebly you turned it on for the FIRST TIME
go to apps, can you run your app from there?
only after the first time it runs you will be able to run the app automatically.